# Generators for $\mathbb F_p^*$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, reference-request, field-theory, finite-fields

Let $p$ be prime, then it is a well-known fact that $\mathbb F_p^*= \mathbb F_p -\{0\}$ is a cyclic group under multiplication. Are there any methods to determine the generators of this cyclic or any results which help in actually finding the generators?

Comment: I like this question a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See chapter 11 of Shoup's [A Computational Introduction to Number Theory and Algebra](http://shoup.net/ntb/). In general this is a difficult problem, but there's a good probabilistic algorithm if you can factor $p-1$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the link.